# ESD causing freeze?

Tags: freeze, esd

I custom built a computer a year or two ago, and as it's becoming winter again, a very annoying problem is surfacing once again...

About 1/2 the time I plug a USB peripheral or my heaphones into the computer, it completely, 100% hard freezes. Not even hitting the reset button brings it back. (The screen goes black but it never POSTs). I have to flip the switch on my PSU and wait till it dies and then turn it back on in order for it to boot again.

The reason I believe it has something do with static is because **it only happens during the winter.** Occasionally, when my hand brushes the case, I get a static shock. Here's the catch though. **Even if I get shocked, it keeps working fine. It's only when I plug in my headphones or a USB device that it happens.**

This is completely OS-independent, it happens with both Linux and Windows 7.

Now, I can accept that the computer is getting ESDed and that is causing problems.

#### HOWEVER:

I have never had this situation happen with pre-built computers. Obviously, the case is grounded, or else there wouldn't be a static shock when I touch it.

### What could possibly be going on here?

---

Relevant specs:

- MB: Asus M5A97 R2.0
- CPU: AMD FX-6300
- GPU: EVGA GTX650
- PSU: Corsair CX500
- Case: Corsair Spec-02

Comment: Is the front-panel or rear-panel ports more susceptible, or seems the same? *"Obviously, the case is grounded, or else there wouldn't be a static shock when I touch it."* -- Incorrect, the case is simply at a lower potential than you.  That doesn't mean that it's *properly* grounded to the electrical system.

Comment: @sawdust - I almost never plug anything into the back, so I can't really answer that.